# Lua is not producing output file

Tags: io, lua, output

I execute the code below but it doesn't create an output file (at least on the directory where the *.lua is)

```
 file = io.open("output.txt","w")
io.output(file)
io.write("hello, reader!")
io.close(file)
```

I am using ZeroBrane Studio on Windows, if that helps

Comment: where from do you run the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file will be created in the project directory you're currently in.

You can click the button `Set project directory from current file` in ZBS when you have your `lua` file open.

By the way, another cleaner looking way to write to a file would be using methods on the file instead, like

```
file = io.open("output.txt","w")
file:write("hello, reader!")
file:close()
```

It does the same thing, looks prettier though.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)